# Non-expensive, effective way to get partition count

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

To make a jQuery `DataTable` work properly, I need the total records contained in a data set, which is then filtered by features in `DataTables` (ie: how many records per page, sort column, sort order, etc.).

But the problem is that each time the UI calls for a page of records, the total amount of records has to be returned as well and I found it's quite costly in terms of RUs. (I have about 750 records now, and calculating the total of records costs 118 RUs every page change). Thing is that there may be TONS of pages available.

Here's what I do to get the count:

```
var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<int>(CollectionURI, "select value count(1) from c", new FeedOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) })
            .AsDocumentQuery();

response = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<int>();
return response.ToList()[0];
```

This works in terms of performance, but RU wise, not so much.

Is there any better way to get the partition's size?

Comment: When I added the CountAsync method in [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) i used the CountAsync method of the SDK. It doesn't return the RU charge but CosmosDB has special charges for special operations so it will probably be cheaper. You can check it in the CosmosDB analytics.

Comment: Didn't know about `CountAsync`. I tried it and it seems cheap in terms of RU. Thanks.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. You can accept it if it did the trick for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL API SDK has a method called `CountAsync` which does all the magic internally.

Such operations have different pricing so using it will be cheaper.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing.